# Finding the maximum total with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two SQL tables in a SQL Server 2008 database that look like the following:

```
Customer
--------
ID
Name

Order
-----
ID
CustomerID
Total
```

I need to figure out what the most number of order placed by a customer has been. At this point, I've gotten here:

```
SELECT MAX([OrderCount]) FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(o.[ID]) as 'OrderCount'
  FROM [Order] o 
  GROUP BY o.[CustomerID]
)
```

When I execute this statement, I get a message that says "Incorrect syntax near ')'". My subquery works. Which would imply the problem is with SELECT MAX([OrderCount]), but everything looks correct to me (granted, i'm not a sql whiz). What am I doing wrong here? Am I even attacking this sql query correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically there:

```
SELECT MAX([OrderCount]) FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(o.[ID]) as 'OrderCount'
  FROM [Order] o 
  GROUP BY o.[CustomerID]
) t
```

You need the alias at the end.

Another way to write this without the subquery is:

```
  SELECT top 1 COUNT(o.[ID]) as OrderCount
  FROM [Order] o 
  GROUP BY o.[CustomerID]
  order by OrderCount desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this:

```
SELECT max(COUNT(o.[ID])) as 'OrderCount'
FROM [Order] o  
GROUP BY o.[CustomerID]
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option with OVER clause

```
SELECT TOP 1 MAX(COUNT(o.[ID])) OVER() AS OrderCount
FROM [Order] o
GROUP BY o.[CustomerID]
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/611bf/1/0)